# How to add several hyperlinks in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, hyperlink

I'm trying to add a conditioned hyperlink in VBA - if one cell shows something (out of four possibilities), then the link is supposed to appear in another cell, on the same sheet, a few columns apart.

"Categorie" is the name of the cell on which content the condition is based. 
I've done this, but nothing appears on the sheet when I press play. Did I make a mistake ?

```
Sub Création_lien()

If Categorie = "Vocabulaire" Then
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("H6"), 
    "https://www.anglaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-anglais-2/exercice-anglais-113622.php"
End If

End Sub
```

I went through it with F8, and it tells me that "Categorie" is empty. 
Here is my Sheet :

There is one list to choose from, and several possibilities that change according to what you choose, in the 4th to 6th column

[image]

As I have several answers that correspond to a same content in cell "Categorie", how can I add several links so they can appear in 9 cells ?

Comment: Use F8 key to step through the code line by line. Also, edit your question and post a screenshot of current data and the expected results

Answer (score 0):

I think all that is missing is to change `Categorie` to `Range("Categorie")`. 
The Visual Basic Editor thinks `Categorie` is a variable, which is why it's empty.

Your other question is how to add multiple links. If the link is dependent on the value of `Categorie` then you might try something like:

```
Sub Création_lien()

Workbooks("Book1").Activate 'put your workbook name here

    If Range("Categorie") = "Vocabulaire" Then
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("H6"), "https://www.anglaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-anglais-2/exercice-anglais-113622.php"
    ElseIf Range("Categorie") = "Some other value" Then
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("H6"), "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59270705/edit"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your option, but then I have an error message. And when I check line by line, it tells me at Range("Categorie") that     '   Range("Categorie")=<Method'Range' of object '_Global' failed>    ' The problem remains. As for the "elseif", I don't think it's what I need. What I need to do is for several cells separatley, in the range (H6; J10) to contain a different link if "Categorie" = "Vocabulaire". And then, if "Categorie" = "Grammaire", I want those same cells to contain another bunch of different links.

Comment: You are most likely receiving this error message because the workbook with the named range is not active. I've added an extra line that will active your workbook. This isn't really best practice in my opinion, but is a simple fix.

Comment: It's open on the desk. How should I make it more active ?

Comment: Assuming that activating the workbook fixes the first issue. Would each cell in the range H6:J10 contain a unique link when `Categorie = "Vocabulaire"`? If so, I don't think there is any way to avoid having many lines like `ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("H6"), "https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59270705/edit"`

Comment: No, each cell would contain a different link :)